# Diffraction pattern threshhold

Tags: optics

What is the characteristic bump height of periodic grating below which diffraction effect cease to exist (let assume a threshold of peaks to valleys intensity of 20% as the minimum detectable by human eye). Is it significantly less than lambda?

Comment: What makes You think that a threschold exists? Diffraction including those by gratings is a strictly linear phenomenon.

Comment: If grating height is below wavelength then it won't disturb wavefront, right? To put it bluntly we can't distinguish structures below wavelength, can we?

Comment: :=) Yes we can!

Comment: Why diffraction is linear? One would think that as soon as the height of grating bump is large we get saturation. In other words, diffraction produced by grating with 1 mm height bumps should be identical to the one with 2 mm. So, my question is what happens when the height is vanishingly small?

Comment: Another hint: there are gratings with zero height!

Comment: I know what happens in the limit. I attempted to plug in sinusoidal grating of height h into Mathematica: Integrate[i*exp(-2*pi*i*sqrt((y-h*sin(x1))^2+(x-x1)^2)/lambda)/(sqrt((y-h*sin(x1))^2+(x-x1)^2)*lambda),{x1,-d,d}] -- it timed out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume sinusoidal grate -- `sin(x)` is the simplest possible periodic function. Direct axis `x` horizontally, and `y` vertically, and lets calculate diffraction at the point `(x,y)`. According to Fraunhofer diffraction we must first calculate distance from the observation point `(x,y)` to the source of secondary wave `(x_1, h*sin(d*x_1)))` which is `r=sqrt((y-h*sin(d*x_1))^2+(x-x_1)^2)`. Here the `h` is the height of the ripple, and `d` its frequency. This r is plugged in into the amplitude integral `Integrate(i*exp(-2*pi*i*r/lambda)/(r*lambda),x1=-R..R)`. Mathematica expression:

```
Integrate[i*exp(-2*pi*i*sqrt((y-h*sin(x1))^2+(x-x1)^2)/lambda)/(sqrt((y-h*sin(x1))^2+(x-x1)^2)*lambda),{x1,-d,d}]
```

Maple:

```
Int(i*exp(-2*pi*i*sqrt((y-h*sin(d*x1))^2+(x-x1)^2)/lambda)/(sqrt((y-h*sin(d*x1))^2+(x-x1)^2)*lambda),x1=-R..R);
```

Neither succeeded solving it analytically, so one have to regress to numerics. Therefore, I assigned the following numeric values:

The radius of the flat mirror:

```
R=20 mm
```

Wavelength:

```
lambda=0.0004 mm (=400 nm)
```

Defect density/frequency:

```
d=10 (10 ripples/mm -- with higher values Wolfram alpha times out)
```

Defect height

```
h=0.0001 mm (1/1 wave)
```

Location

```
y=100 mm (10 cm above the mirror).
```

With all the assignments the only free variable remaining is x, so one should be able to plot intensity graph. Unfortunately, Wolfram Alpha refuse to understand what `Plot[Integral[]]` is and suggests some stock market graphs instead. I had to calculate pointwise. Here is an expression which calculates intensity at the axis (`x=0`):

```
Integral[i*exp(-2*pi*i*sqrt((100-0.0001*sin(10*x1))^2+(0.0-x1)^2)/0.0004)/(sqrt((100-0.0001*sin(10*x1))^2+(0.0-x1)^2)*0.0004),x1=-20..20]
```

Which walpfa evaluates to `0.62+3.81i`

The characteristic angle of periodic grating is `lambda*d` so the diffraction pattern linear dimension is `lambda*d*y` which in our case is conveniently `1`. Therefore, we could see diffraction pattern by probing only three points: `x=0.0`, `x=0.5`, and `x=1.0`. Here are the intensities:

```
x=0.0 -> 0.62+3.81*i
x=0.5 -> 7.76+3.0*i
x=1.0 -> 3.51+1.8*i
```

In other words, the diffraction pattern is quite noticeable when defect size is comparable to lambda. To doublecheck, what if we shrink grating height 10 fold? There:

```
x=0.0 -> 3.4+3.5*i
x=0.5 -> 4.1+3.1*i
x=1.0 -> 3.88+3.33*i
```